# How to reduce indentation size within loop of an algorithm

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algorithm2e

For the following algorithm, I get four spaces for each text line inside the loop. How can I get only two or three spaces? Some of my text lines go to next line. I want to save some horizontal spaces.

```
\usepackage[noline,boxruled,commentsnumbered,linesnumbered,titlenumbered]{algorithm2e}

\IncMargin{0.5em}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\SetKwFor{Foreach}{for each}{do}{endfor}
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{endif}
\BlankLine
\Input{A method \emph{m}}
\Output{result}
\BlankLine
\Foreach { $x \in M_{x}$}{
 do something
}
\caption{Algorithm}\label{Method}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). You can control the indentation via `\SetInd{0.1ex}{0.1ex}`, where the first parameter is the space before, and the 2nd is the space after.  It would be helpful if you turned your code into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: It worked. I was using 'em', instead of 'ex' within parameters. I will put complete code next time. :)

Comment: Oppps, `em` is actually the correct unit to use for horizontal spacing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
\SetInd{<space before>}{<space after>}
```

to control the spacing before and after the vertical rule (which is disabled via that `noline` option).  Here is a comparison of the default setting and one with `\SetInd{0.25em}{0.1em}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noline,boxruled,commentsnumbered,linesnumbered,titlenumbered]{algorithm2e}

\IncMargin{0.5em}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Without setting \verb|\SetInd{}{}|: 
\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\SetKwFor{Foreach}{for each}{do}{endfor}
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{endif}
\BlankLine
\Input{A method \emph{m}}
\Output{result}
\BlankLine
\Foreach { $x \in M_{x}$}{
 do something
}
\caption{Algorithm}\label{Method}
\end{algorithm}

\noindent
With \verb|\SetInd{0.25em}{0.1em}|:
\SetInd{0.25em}{0.1em}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\SetKwFor{Foreach}{for each}{do}{endfor}
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{endif}
\BlankLine
\Input{A method \emph{m}}
\Output{result}
\BlankLine
\Foreach { $x \in M_{x}$}{
 do something
}
\caption{Algorithm}\label{Method}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```